# In macOS, is there a keyboard shortcut to move windows to other desktops?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces

[Mission Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) allows for multiple desktop (spaces). Does there exist a keyboard shortcut for moving an application's window from one to another?

Answer (score 7):

You can hold the window with your mouse and use the usual keyboard shortcuts to move the window across desktops.

Comment: Works in Ventura. This is the best compromise I can find without extra software. BetterTouchTool's download page gave me a 404.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use a third party application, like BetterTouchTool, which allows you to bind key combinations to user defined actions, including moving windows between spaces.

Comment: This is the best solution I have found. In BetterTouchTool's preferences, choose "Add New Shortcut.., and then choose "Move Window One Space/Desktop Left|Right" from "Trigger Predefined Action"

Answer (score 2):

This requires you to use the touchpad or mouse, but: Hold the window (at the top bar) with your touchpad or mouse and use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, etc. to move a window to another space. ( <kbd>control</kbd> is the <kbd>^</kbd> key).

Comment: This shortcut can also be customized in System Settings->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts->Mission Control->Mission Control.